# Speed up "sleep" in Ruby

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, cucumber, sleep

In my codes, there are many places I purposely puts "sleep", just because the features are required to be so. However, when I do testing using RSpec or Cucumber, it becomes a nuisance because it takes so long to complete the tests.

Updated: thanks for some of the suggestions. However either stub or manually redefining might be cumbersome. What I imagine is just a tweak call to speed up "sleep" with a scale.

There is this gem timecop. It can speed up Time.now by a scale. If such idea can be applied to sleep, that would be great!

Reference:
https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop

---

Updated:sorry for late response, below may illustrate my situation:

```
class SomeClass
    def some_method
        sleep 15
        make_api_call_A
        sleep 45
        make_api_call_B
    end
end

describe SomeClass do
    before do
        Acceleration.speed_up(10) # speed time up to 10x
    end

    after do
        Acceleration.reset
    end

    if "should make two API calls" do
        subject.some_method
    end
end
```

As you can see there are two sleeps with different durations in some_method. What I prefer is, instead of waiting 60s, if I can speed up sleep time to 10x, I just have to wait for 6s. That fastens the testing process a lot.

Comment: Just replace the hard coded `sleep` values with a variable / configuration.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what your problem is. Can you add an example in which your feature requires `sleep`?

Comment: How is stubbing "cumbersome"? This is the kind of thing that stubbing was invented for.

Comment: Why are you using sleeps? Use polling instead.

Comment: Hi, I updated my question, please have a look if you are still interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to scale sleep, you can override `Kernel.sleep` method this way:

```
module Acceleration
  mattr_accessor :sleep_scale

  def self.speed_up(scale)
    self.sleep_scale = scale
  end

  def self.reset
    self.sleep_scale = 1
  end

  reset
end

module Kernel
  alias :original_sleep :sleep

  def sleep(time)
    original_sleep(time / Acceleration.sleep_scale.to_f)
  end
end

class SomeClass
  def some_method
      sleep 15
      make_api_call_A
      sleep 45
      make_api_call_B
  end
end

describe SomeClass do
  before do
    Acceleration.speed_up(10) # speed time up to 10x
  end

  after do
    Acceleration.reset
  end

  it "should make two API calls" do
    subject.some_method
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thanks a lot. It works. Also I would incorporate more features to make it a gem. Would you want to be credited when it's published? :)

Answer (score 4):

You need stub `sleep` calls in your specs.

```
class SomeClass
  def some_method
    sleep 10
  end
end

describe SomeClass do
  before do
    subject.stub!(:sleep)
  end

  it "should call sleep" do
    subject.should_receive(:sleep).with(10)
    subject.some_method
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi, I updated my question, please have a look if you are still interested.

Answer (score 1):

Temporarily add the following only when you test.

```
def sleep *; end
```

Answer (score 0):

### Monkey-Patch Kernel#sleep

Assuming that you really have a valid use case here, and you don't want to refactor your code to avoid hard-coded sleep values or disable sleeping altogether, you can simply monkey-patch [Kernel#sleep](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sleep) within your specs to use a scaled factor. For example, to make sleep run ten times faster (e.g. for 1/10 the specified time):

```
module Kernel
  alias_method :old_sleep, :sleep
  def sleep seconds
    old_sleep(seconds * 0.1)
  end  
end
```

### Benchmark Your Scaling

Once you've monkey-patched sleep, you can test that your scaling works with [Benchmark#realtime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html#method-c-realtime):

```
require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.realtime { sleep 10 }.round 2
#=> 1.0

Benchmark.realtime { sleep 0.1 }.round 2
#=> 0.01
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution which in my opinion is easier and doesn't add more dependencies to your project:

In the class, put the sleep time into a constant, for example:

```
WAITING_TIME = 45
```

Call `sleep` with this constant instead of a number:

```
sleep WAITING_TIME
```

In the test use `stub_const` from `RSpec` to change the time used for sleeping:

```
before do
  stub_const('MyClass::WAITING_TIME', 4.5)
end
```

That is all. You don't need to mock the `sleep` call, you don't need an additional gem for this, and `RSpec` will take care of stubbing the constant and resetting it back at the end of the test.